# Ion Android getHeaders

Tags: android, android-ion

How do I get a specific header using the Ion network library for Android?

This is what I'm trying:

```
...
.setCallback(new FutureCallback<Response<String>>() {
    @Override
    public void onCompleted(Exception e, Response<String> result) {
        System.out.println("header: " + result.getHeaders().message("mykey"));
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

message(String) sets the HTTP response message. I should make that internal to avoid confusion.

Use

```
getHeaders().getHeaders().get(String)
```

It's a bit obtuse at the moment, will need to clean that API up in the next release.